# iOS Facebook SDK error language

Tags: ios, facebook, localization

I am wondering if the Facebook SDK for iOS provides a method for localizing the error messages.
From here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/ I learned that there's an easy way to get a description of e.g. Login errors which you can display to the user:

```
[FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error];
```

But that only returns an english version. Is there any way to automatically translate that to a different language? Or a different method to return a localized string? Otherwise this convenient method would be kind of useless for non-english apps.

Regards
Kim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out myself.
I had to create a bundle file, set it in the .plist under the key "FacebookBundleName" and overwrite the needed Error Message key/value pairs there.
Took me a while to get it running, but the Scrumptious sample helped me figure it out.

See "How can I localize the Facebook images and strings?" in
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting/